# Image_tag with Link_to helper in a ternary operator condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get a sample of the latest 3 products on sell inside my store first-page view and make them clickable to redirect the user to their reciprocal show page.
This is the controller:

```
  def home
  @productsample = Product.where(:ordinable => true).last(3).shuffle
  end
```

This is my view:

```
<h2>Latest product on sell!</h2>
<% @productsample.each do |x| %>
<div>
  <%= x.picture? ? link_to image_tag(x.picture_url, :alt => x.name), product_path(x) : image_tag("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250") %>
</div>
```

for some reason i don't understand i keep getting this sintax error:

```
/home/luis/code/levisn1/development/ezmarkt/app/views/pages/home.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' x.picture? ? link_to image_tag(x.picture_url, :alt => x.name ^ /home/luis/code/levisn1/development/ezmarkt/app/views/pages/home.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' .picture_url, :alt => x.name), root_path : image_tag("https: ^
```

with this code, instead, it works perfectly of course:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(x.picture_url), product_path(x) %>
```

what's the right syntax to get my first code working? Thanks

Comment: I guess you also missed closing ```<% end %>``` for your ```each``` block

Comment: I just forgot to copy the rest of the iteration's code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems youre trying to use ternary operator to decide what to display. Try:

```
  <%= x.picture? ? (link_to image_tag(x.picture_url, :alt => x.name), root_path) : image_tag("https://via.placeholder.com/250x250") %>
```

I think the comma between the arguments for `link_to` method is throwing the syntax error, so now that the `link_to` method with it's arguments is inside round brackets it should not break the syntax for ternary operator.